# Compare values in GroupBy and count the matching rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

This is a sample row I have in my data frame:

```
{
"sessionId" : "454ec8b8-7f00-40b2-901c-724c5d9f5a91",
"useCaseId" : "3652b5d7-55b8-4bee-82b6-ab32d5543352",
"timestamp" : "1559403699899",
"endFlow" : "true"
}
```

And there are 100s of rows like this with similar/different 'sessionId','useCaseId' and 'endFlow' values. I'm grouping it by 'sessionId' and 'useCaseId' as follows:

```
groupby_session_usecase = seperate_dates_df.groupby(['sessionId','useCaseId'])
```

Within the groups in 'groupby_session_usecase', I want to find if there's any row who's 'endFlow' value is 'true'. I have tried the following:

```
'true' in groupby_session_usecase['endFlow']
```

However, the above line always returns 'False' even if there are 'endFlow' values equal to 'true'

**Whats the correct approach to check if there's any row within the  groups in 'groupby_session_usecase' having 'endFlow' value equal to 'true'?**

Comment: If "true" exists anywhere in the DataFrame, then does that not imply it exists inside a group? Why do you actually need to call groupby to do that?

Comment: @cs95, Because I have to take a count of 'endFlow=true' based on 'sessionId' and 'useCaseId'. Any idea how to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP writes:

> "I have to take a count of 'endFlow=true' based on 'sessionId' and
>   'useCaseId'. Any idea how to achieve this requirement?"

Yes, all you have to do is to compare the rows first, then group on that result using `SeriesGroupBy.sum()`.

```
(df['endFlow'] == "true").groupby([df['session'], df['useCaseId']]).sum()
```

Alternatively, you can assign the comparison back to `df`, then your grouping becomes slightly simpler:

```
(df.assign(msk=df['endFlow'].eq('true'))
   .groupby(['session', 'useCaseId'])['msk']
   .sum())
```